# Elasticbeanstalk django projoject deployment decouple link error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting this error while uploading .ebextension file which containing two file , first config file like this :

```
    packages:
      yum:
        freetype-devel: []
        libffi-devel: []
        libpng-devel: []
        libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
        libevent: []
        libevent-devel: []
        nginx: []
        git: []
   .............
.............
```

> Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...6/site-packages/decouple.py",
>   line 70, in get raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as
>   envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
>   decouple.UndefinedValueError: FACEBOOK_APP_ID not found. Declare it as
>   envvar or define a default value. container_command 01_migratedb in
>   .ebextensions/02_deploy_app.config failed. For more detail, check
>   /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Environment showing red mark. 
I've used 'python-decouple' package. for that reason I've created .env file where every environment variable are perfectly declared. but aws elastice beanstalk are failed to connect that file, that's why environment variable are not uploading properly, for that issue. any suggestion please ...

Answer (score 0):

go to instance configuration and fill all variable with environment value.